# make visible checkbox after selecting radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

Firstly, all checkboxes would be hidden. then after the user select a radio, i want to display the checkbox related to that. I don't know JQuery.. but i know Javascript. any solutions?

```
<html><body>
<div id="page">
<div>
<form action="book.php">
<h2><b>Source: </b></h2>
<input type="radio" name="sl"  value="c">Central</input>
<input type="radio" name="sl"  value="h">Eastern</input>
<input type="radio" name="sl" value="w">Western</input>
</br></br>


<select id="sc">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="sh">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="sw">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>


</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried writing any javascript?

Comment: i have no idea what to try. you can suggest any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way, and with a little bit of css:

#### JS

```
window.onload = function () {
    var allElem = document.getElementsByName("sl");
    for (i = 0; i < allElem.length; i++) {
        allElem[i].addEventListener('change', toggleDisplay); //register event to the radio button.
    }

}

function toggleDisplay(e) {
   var id = 's' + this.value; //get the value caculate the id of the target element.
    var currentSelect = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0]; //remove currently active select
    if (currentSelect) {
        currentSelect.className = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(id).className = "active"; //set active classname to the new target
}
```

#### CSS

```
form select {
    display:none;
}
form select.active {
    display:block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XP4VJ/)**

Incase of jquery just this will help:

```
$(function () {
    $('[name="sl"]').change(function () {
        var target = '#s' + this.value;
        $(target).show().siblings('select').hide();
    })
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Wga/)**

Comment: @SanjayMalhotra you are welcome. if you dont want to support IE7 and older browsers we can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector instead of elementsByName, id etc.. If you support jquery lines of code can be minimized. But i did not add the JQ solution since you did not tag jquery.. Anyways chalo..

Comment: @SanjayMalhotra ok added a solution with jquery for your future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain JavaScript, I'd suggest:

```
function showSelects (radio) {
    var id = 's' + radio.value,
        curActive = document.querySelector('select.active'),
        target = document.getElementById(id);
    if (curActive !== null) {
        curActive.classList.remove('active');
    }
    target.classList.add('active');
}

var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name=sl]');
for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
    radios[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
        showSelects(this);
    });
}
```

The above requires the following CSS:

```
select {
    display: none;
}

select.active {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8CxZN/).

This is, though, restricted to fairly up-to-date browsers.

With jQuery it'd be as simple as:

I'd suggest:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=s1]').change(function(){
    var self = this;
    $('#s' + self.value).show();
}).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to show/hide the IDs if the radio buttons are checked.

Using your HTML example, you can do something like this (note that you need to give the `<form>` an ID, here I am using `form-id`:

```
$('#form-id').change(function() {
    if ($('#one').prop('checked')) {
        $('#sc').show();
    } else {
        $('#sc').hide();
    }
});
```

Additionally you will need to have your CSS doing something like:

```
#sc,#sh,#sw { display: none;}
```

[**JSFiddle Example - click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hE3Eb/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know jQuery but would like to use it, try going to codeschool and doing their free course.  It's really good.

Pure Javascript:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("sl");

var selects = [];
selects.push(document.getElementById("sc"));
selects.push(document.getElementById("sh"));
selects.push(document.getElementById("sw"));

for (i=0;i<radios.length;i++) {
  radios[i].onclick = function(){
    for (j=0;j<selects.length;j++) {
      selects[j].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("s"+radios[i].value).style.display = 'block';
  };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2CMH/

Answer (score 0):

pure jQuery

```
$('#switchers input').change(function() {
    var select = $('#s' + $(this).val());
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        select.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        select.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8wzd6/